# Tag synonym request: [debug] -> [debugging]

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

I think [debug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debug) should be a synonym of [debugging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debugging).

They have identical tag wiki excerpts and cover the same thing, although it's extremely wide and needs to have additional tags included to narrow down.

I still think that [debugging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debugging) should be the master tag in this case.

Comment: Note that all [tag:debug] questions should likely be tagged with [tag:debugging] going forward.

Comment: I'm so old-school that to me debug means a program and debugging means a process, I would agree that most of the debug questions here should be tagged debugging, and going forward questions to do with the process of debugging should be tagged as such rather than tagged debug.

Comment: @ThomasWard want to use your mod powers for this now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not delete both of them instead? Neither [debug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debug) nor [debugging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debugging) give any useful information. In fact, they seem like prime examples of [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). For those who don't know, meta-tags are tags that

1. Can’t work as the only tag on a question.
2. Commonly mean different things to different people.

If I see a question tagged with [debugging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debugging), what do I know? That the OP has a problem. Well yes, they wouldn't really be posting here otherwise. About 95.3% of all AU questions are about debugging something or other. What is this one about? Debugging hardware issues? A compilation error? A script? Someone's software? A dpkg issue?

The [debug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debug) tag is not adding anything useful to the question and needs a helper tag in order to actually mean anything. So, forget synonyms, let's burn it with fire instead!

Comment: Excellent point.

Comment: I think it should stay but it should not apply to problems with that package, that hardware or ... . It should apply to debugging that is to Ubuntu-specific but otherwise would have been posted on SO, UnixLinux, SuperUser, or ServerFault.

Comment: @user877329 anything that is not Ubuntu specific should be posted on other sites anyway.

Comment: @terdon Linux distros share some behaviour but may differ. Perhaps there should be a askdebian, askfedora...

Comment: @user877329 in my opinion there should only be [unix.se] but never mind. The point is that `debugging` gives no useful information. We already know that a question here needs to be about Ubuntu and needs to be about solving some issue or other.

Comment: @terdon What about developer-debugging. I think "Catch program crash when there is no terminal" is a debugging question, more than "How do I get feature X work". The former is more a question about debugging aids while the latter asks for a concrete solution.

Comment: @user877329 that would be a different situation since there is something qualifying the _debugging_. My problem is that _debugging_ alone gives no useful information.